# Appium Inspector connection error

Tags: java, android, appium, inspector

When I click on 'refresh' button on Appium inspector I got an connection error. When I searched on this site, I learned that apk location should be added on Android Settings page of Appium. However I am testing an application with its source code not an apk file. I want to use inspector for its record&replay property, thats why I don't want to use UIAutomatorviewer. Can you inform me about usage of inspector with source code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have source code of Android app that you want to create automation for, you would have to first build it either using Android Studio or Eclipse. Appium operates on the app as a black box, hence it needs an apk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I am able to connect inspector but is it true that record&replay property is not available on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the .apk first. You can use android studio for that. Your .apk will locate at
/Yourproject/app/build/outputs/apk/yourproject.apk

Answer (score 0):

Appium wont work with source code and it require APK path